# Página de Login Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Estou tentando criar uma página de login sem ser aquela do wp-admin, quero criar uma personalizada,e não posso utilizar plugin, alguma dica ou exemplo de como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, eu já cheguei a fazer isso uma vez e foi dessa maneira abaixo:

```
<?php 
global $user_login;

        // Login form arguments. 'redirect' => ( is_ssl() ? 'https://' : 'http://' ) . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
        $args = array(
            'echo'           => true,
            'redirect'       => home_url( '/meu-painel/' ),
            'form_id'        => 'loginform',
            'label_username' => __( 'Username' ),
            'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
            'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
            'label_log_in'   => __( 'Log In' ),
            'id_username'    => 'user_login2',
            'id_password'    => 'user_pass2',
            'id_remember'    => 'rememberme',
            'id_submit'      => 'wp-submit',
            'remember'       => true,
            'value_username' => NULL,
            'value_remember' => true
        ); 

        // Calling the login form.
        wp_login_form( $args );
     ?>
```

Basta inserir esse código aonde você deseja no template. Depois só teria que tratar a questão da validação, em caso de erro.

Veja que, após o login, defini o redirecionamento (redirect) para a página "Meu painel".

Espero que te ajude!

Comment: Essa solução eu já tinha visto, deixa eu explicar um pouco melhor o meu problema,eu criei um custom_post_type, e adicionei um menu login no painel do wordpress, o que eu quero é que os futuros usuarios do meu sistema façam login pela página login que criei e que o login não seja pegando os dados do wp-admin e sim do meu menu login no painel do wordpress

Comment: Espera aí que ficou confuso um pouco. O cara já vai estar logado no padrão do wp, correto? Daí você quer que os usuários façam um segundo login para acessar determinado ambiente? É isso?

Comment: Não exatamente, seria assim, a pessoa entraria no http://example.com e apareceria a tela de login que criei ai ela digitaria o login dela, mas a questão é que não quero que o login venha do wordpress, como seria o normal em entraria em usuarios e criaria um usuario para ela e tal, e sim que os dados que compararia seria para o menu login que criei no painel do wordpress, entendeu? basicamente quero substituir de onde vem as informações para entrar no sistema, de usuarios para esse login que criei

Comment: Entendi. Cara, no caso aí você vai ter que desenvolver uma programação a parte. Pelo que vejo, não é uma coisa simples. Tipo terá que criar tabelas no banco para armazenar os dados dos usuários e depois partir pra codificação. Pra mim, nunca tinha visto essa situação.